# Linux Mint wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, wifi-configuration

I'm running Linux Mint 15 Xfce on a Compaq Presario desktop from 2009. I can't seem to get the wifi working. Rather than ask a general question, here's a simple question:

If

$> iwlist wlan0 scanning

returns all the wireless networks available, that means that my wifi card is working, nyet?

So, if that's true, then the problem is that I'm just not setting it up properly, isn't that so?

Lastly, is it a mistake to try to set up a wireless connection on Mint by configuring files, rather than use their GUI wireless system (which seems not to work properly)? This is for my girlfriend who wants to try linux. I personally use slackware, but I thought I'd try Mint for her cause it's supposed to be so easy.

My slackware config parameters fail on Mint.

Oy.

TIA

Comment: if it sees wireless networks, you would think it should work...  is the chipset supported?  Also, I always use the GUI, never failed for me before.

Comment: Keltari - thx. Can you tell me the tool you use to configure the wifi? What version of Mint do you use?